# Get object position within view within scroll view

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiscrollview, scrollview

I have such hierarchy:

- scroll view
- --- container view
- ----- cycle view

[image]

This **scroll view** also can zoom.
And I need to show *view2* in center of cycle view when I pressed this **cycle view**(there I have tap gesture recogniser). But **view2** should be lye on **container view** because we also need to zoom it with **cycle view**.

I try to get rect where need to show **view2** with this approach.

```
func getSourceRect(for cycleView: UIView) -> CGRect {
   let rectOnContainer = cycleView.convert(cycleView.frame, to: containerView)
   let rectOnScrollView = containerView.convert(rectOnContainer, to: scrollView)
        
   return rectOnScrollView
}
```

and then I do next

```
let sourceRect = getSourceRect(for: cycleView)
view2.center = CGPoint(x: sourceRect.midX, y: sourceRect.midY)
```

It doesn't work.
Please help me understood this behaviour and get this position where I can show **view2**

Comment: So you want view2 to be centered on the cycle view but attached to the container view?

Comment: Is cycleview's parent container view?

Comment: @Biclops yes, need to be centered. And also cycleview's parent is container view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want view2 to be centered on the cycle view but attached to the container view?

If this is true then

```
// if view2 and cycle view's parent is container view 
// then there should not be a need to transform view2's 
// coordinate space
view2.center = cycleView.center

// make sure z position is correct so that cycle view isn't obscuring
// view2's visibility.
view2.parent?.bringSubviewToFront(view2)
```